# WriteLine both expression and the resulting value?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I often need to log or write values of expression and also something that gives context to that.  So for example:

```
WriteLine($"_managedHandlePtr:{_managedHandlePtr}");
WriteLine($"metadata.GetNative(_ptr, handle):{metadata.GetNative(_ptr, handle)}");
```

Is it possible to get the original expression from an interpolated string?  Something like the below in concept. It would be nice if I could eliminate the stringly part of this but get the same output:

```
LogExpression($"{_managedHandlePtr}");
LogExprsssion($"{metadata.GetNative(_ptr, handle)}");

// Writes the non-interpolated string expression, a colon, then the evaluated string
void LogExpression(FormattableString formattableString)
{
  Console.WriteLine(${formattableString.GetExpression()}:{formattableString.ToString()});
}
```

Output:

```
_managedHandlePtr:213456
metadata.GetNative(_ptr, handle):0xG5DcS4
```

It would also be fine if it had to include the notation from the original string:

```
{_managedHandlePtr}:213456
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to do structured logging.  Consider using serilog instead of interpolated string. It is however possible to get some information out of FormattedString, it really isn't enough...

Comment: `void LogExpression(Expression<Func<string>> expression) => Console.WriteLine($"{expression.ToString()}:{expression.Compile()()}");`
is close, just don't expect a pretty expression
to call: `LogExpression(() => $"{metadata.GetNative(_ptr, handle)}");`

Comment: @Aron Maybe I'm not understanding, but doesn't that only really work when logging POCOs?  It's going to serialize the object/property names, but not necessarily names of variables/locals nor expression.

Comment: You have to assign a name to each variable you are logging with Serilog. Its not an exact fit for your question, because there are no hard guarantees that the name you choose is the name of the variable in the source. So yes, it is for logging POCOs, but it also assigns a name to each POCO you log.

Comment: Trust me, you want to use Serilog with Splunk/ELK for structured log searches. It will save your life

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get much more than the types of the arguments of the `FormtableString`.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Number a = new Number(1.0);     // 1.0
        Percent b = new Percent(2.0);   // 2%
        double c = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine(Format($"{a} + {b} = {c}"));
        // Number + Percent = Double : 1 + 2% = 1.02
    }

    static string Format(this FormattableString expression, CultureInfo info = null)
    {
        if (info == null)
        {
            info = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }
        object[] names = expression.GetArguments().Select((arg) => arg.GetType().Name).ToArray();
        return $"{string.Format(expression.Format, names)} : {expression.ToString(info)}";
    }
}
```